# Putting specific element into variable

Tags: javascript, html

how can i get a specific element of a text input into a variable  via javascript, in other words take the example below

```
   <form id="123">

        <input type="text" id="supply_qty" />

     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="123" />
  </form>
```

How do i get the element within the text input into a variable when the submit button is clicked, the problem i have is that i have multiple instances of the code above, with lots of text inputs, so i only want to get the element specific to the submit button clicked. Hopefully you will get what i mean. The reason i need this done via JavaScript and not php etc... is that i later want to use ajax with it, but for the moment i just need the variable.

Thanks

Comment: Every ID should be unique. Both form and input should not have `id="123"`.

Comment: And here's a nice jQuery answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Yes, the `id` must be unique. In your case both your forms and submit button have same `id` so use class as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to give and `id` to the element and user `getElementById()` method to grab the element on variable. *Just like what you are doing right now*

Simple Example:

```
var button = document.getElementyById("123");
button.onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('supply_qty'); //now you got your element in varaiblle
};
```

Using jQuery make a slight change to your markup. I am just going to add some classes.

```
   <form>
        <input type="text" class="textbox" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
```

then

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    var txtbox = $(this).parent("form").children(".textbox")[0];
});
```

Or, it might be better to bind to the submit handler of the form, on that case, give a common class to the form.

```
   <form class="tinyforms">
        <input type="text" class="textbox" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" />
   </form>
```

Then

```
$('.tinyforms').submit(function() {
    var txtbox = $(this).children(".textbox")[0];
});
```

Comment: Ok great, but say i had 100 submit buttons that had text inputs attached to them, would i need to write the code your provided 100 times, or is there a way to condense it down?

Comment: @Arken, Are you comfortable with jQuery? I could provide a simple understandable code that way more.

Comment: ok that looks great, so the `var txtbox` should hold the value of the textbox?

Comment: @Arken, It holds the reference to whole `txtbox` you can use, `txtbox.value` to get the value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16146/discussion-between-arken-and-starx)

Comment: @Arken, The reason your fiddle didn't work was because of `children` follows as per the DOM tree so, you can use `.find()` instead of `children()`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DygeB/1/) is a working version

Answer (score 0):

If you accept using jQuery you can do this:

DOM

```
<form class="form" action="false">
    <input type="text" value="some input" name="textInput" />
    <input type="text" value="some text" name="textInput2" />
    <input type="submit" class="sumbit" value="Send" />
    <div id="results"></div>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And JavaScript

```
$(".form").submit( function(){
    var inputs = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.each(inputs , function(i, input){
        $("#results").append(input.value + "<br />");
    });
    return false;
} );​
```

EDIT: Updated code and Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/65Xtp/4/

Comment: ok, but will the code work if i had, say 10-15 different forms, each containing their own text input and submit button?

Comment: They will. The event will trigger the parent specific submit buttons parent form, and just get those inputs. In this example every form needs the `class="form"`, and every submit button needs `class="submit"`, but you could as easily remove that.

Comment: i tested your code, but i don't seem to get any output, i am not sure why, i just copied your code and changed the form class and submit class to my own?

Comment: actually i just noticed that i do get an output, it outputs the result to the header like this `?supp_bro_qty_input=123&supp_bro_add_to_cart=Submit` Is there anyway to only get the value of the text input into a variable?

Comment: Hi, i tried your update, but for some reason i still am not getting any output, not even in the results div, its weird,  can't seem to find any reason why, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Do you have names on all your inputs, and classes on the submit buttons and forms?

Comment: Without more specific code I can't help you. The fiddle I made works fine, so I can't say what your problem is. Sorry.