# Get multiple data inputs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's probably a very basic question, but I wasn't sure how to Google it.

I got this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cboxFormButton1").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.colorbox({
href: $(this).closest('form').attr ('action'),
data: {a: $("input#aaa").val()}
});

return false;
});
});
```

and this form:

```
<form action="rrr1.php" method="POST" target="_blank" class="">
    <input id="aaa" name="a" type="hidden" value="1"/>
    <input id="bbb" name="b" type="hidden" value="2"/>
    <input type="submit" id="cboxFormButton1" class="button" value="Test">
</form>
```

right now the code extracts only the data for the "a" input and pass it on to the PHP.
what do I need to change this line to:

```
data: {a: $("input#aaa").val()}
```

so it would get the data for the "b" input as well?

Comment: `data: {
    a: $("#aaa").val(),
    b: $('#bbb').val()
}` ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Why are you doing it like this? Your going backwards.

Comment: @RPM what are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
data: {
  a: $("input#aaa").val(), 
  b: $("input#bbb").val()
}
```