# When Submitting a form the input value attribute is getting submitted instead of the actual input

Tags: javascript, html

This is strange?

I'm using basic HTML CSS and JavaScript my code transpires as the following:

Code:

HTML:

```
 <section class="newsletter-wrapper" id="newsletter">
  <div class="content-newsletter">
    <div class="newsletter-header">
      <h1>Register Yourself to the Club Below</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-newsletter">
      <form id="submit-to-google-sheet">
        <div id="step1">
          <input type="email" name="Email" value="name@email.com" placeholder="Enter Email Here" required />
          <button class="newsletter-button next-button" role="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="step2" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" name="First_Name" placeholder="Enter First Name" required />
          <button class="newsletter-button next-button" role="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="step3" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" name="Last_Name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required  />
          <button class="newsletter-button next-button" role="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="step4" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" name="Interested_Day_Of_Registration" placeholder="Enter interested day to signup" required/>
          <button class="newsletter-button next-button" role="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="step5" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" name="Year_Of_Birth" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" required  />
          <button class="newsletter-button next-button" role="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="step6" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" name="Parents_Name" placeholder="Enter Parent's Name"  />
          <button class="newsletter-button next-button" role="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="step7" style="display:none;">
          <input type="tel" name="Phone_NO." placeholder="Enter Phone Number" required  />
          <button class="newsletter-button next-button" role="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="step8" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" name="CFC_ID" placeholder="Enter CFC ID" />
          <button class="newsletter-button next-button" role="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="step9" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" name="Existing_Other_Family_Member" rows="4" placeholder="Enter exsisting Siblings (optional)"/>
          <button class="newsletter-button" role="button">Subscribe <i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i> </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <span id="msg"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
    .newsletter-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .content-newsletter{
    background: #b37b3c;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    
    .content-newsletter .newsletter-header h1{
    font-size: 230%;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    }
    
    .footer-newsletter{
    padding: 15px;
    }
    
    input{
    border: unset;
    background-color: var(--input-background);
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    }
    
    .newsletter-button{
    background-color: var(--button-background);
    color: #fff;
    border: unset;
    width: 155px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease
    }
    
    .newsletter-button:hover{
    background-color: #ff5500;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
    input:focus,
    .footer-newsletter:focus{
    outline: none;
    }
    
span{
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0.31em;
}
    
span:hover{
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: black;
}
    
button{
    text-wrap: nowrap
}
    
    
input[type="email"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="tel"],
textarea {
    border: unset;
    background-color: var(--input-background);
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 250px;
}
    
.next-button {
    background-color: var(--button-background);
    color: #fff;
    border: unset;
    width: 155px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
    
.next-button:hover {
    background-color: #ff5500;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
    
textarea {
    width: 250px;
    resize: none;
}
    
input:focus,
.footer-newsletter:focus,
textarea:focus 
{
    outline: none;
}

    const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet'];
    const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    const newsletter = document.getElementById('newsletter');
    const submissionDate = localStorage.getItem('submissionDate');
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    
      // Get the current date and time
      const currentDate = new Date().getTime();
    
      // Get the date and time of the most recent submission from localStorage
      const lastSubmissionDate = localStorage.getItem('submissionDate');
    
      if (!lastSubmissionDate || (currentDate - lastSubmissionDate) >= (10)) {
        // If there is no previous submission date or if 24 hours have passed since the last submission,
        // submit the form and store the current date in localStorage
        form.reset();
    
        fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(e.target)})
          .then(response => {
            form.style.display = "none";
            msg.textContent = "You have signed up, we limit devices to one submission per day.";
            console.log('Message Sent Successfully');
            localStorage.setItem('submissionDate', currentDate);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error!', error.message);
            alert("An Error occurred, please contact support with the following error: ", error, error.message);
          });
      } else {
        // If 24 hours have not passed since the last submission, hide the form and display a message to the user
        newsletter.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
```

I'm also using some custom Javascript to handle the next button clicks:

```
const steps = document.querySelectorAll("#submit-to-google-sheet > div");
const nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".next-button");
let currentStep = 0;

nextButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Hide the current step
    steps[currentStep].style.display = "none";

    // Show the next step
    currentStep++;
    steps[currentStep].style.display = "block";

    // Clear the input of the previous step
    // const inputs = steps[currentStep - 1].querySelectorAll("input, textarea");
    // inputs.forEach((input) => {
    //   input.value = "";
    // });
  });
});
```

### and Finally the jamie wilson code is the same as the code he provided, and for the spreadsheet and followed his exact steps.

The Problem:

This is so odd, when I submit the form, nothing happens, I have tried everything and even console.log one by one all my code and nothing changed. However, when I added a value attribute to the initial email input and some values to other input, and then clicked submit, but didn't like erase the initial set value, the form will submit successfully and appear in the spreadsheet, however if I delete the value attribute, or when I actually type my input and delete the value attribute the code will not submit.

Hopefully this makes sense,

I have never seen anything like this and tried everywhere to find a response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FormData created from an existing form seems empty when I log it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040479/formdata-created-from-an-existing-form-seems-empty-when-i-log-it)

Comment: i dont think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your form submits an empty value is because you reset the value of the form just before posting the form's data.

```
      if (!lastSubmissionDate || (currentDate - lastSubmissionDate) >= (10)) {
        // If there is no previous submission date or if 24 hours have passed since the last submission,
        // submit the form and store the current date in localStorage
        form.reset(); //here
    
        fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(e.target)})
```

Remove the reset function and add it to the response function of your fetch call.

```
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(e.target)})
          .then(response => {
            form.style.display = "none";
            msg.textContent = "You have signed up, we limit devices to one submission per day.";
            console.log('Message Sent Successfully');
            localStorage.setItem('submissionDate', currentDate);
            form.reset(); //reset the form here
          })
```