# jquery ajax won't send post data

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, post, upload

I'm creating an ajax upload file. I have written my upload code using PHP and it works fine. The problem is when I use $.ajax{}. The form data cannot be received by my upload.php. Here is my code.

```
function pleaseUpload(){
$(document).ready(function(){
        //var fd=new FormData($("form#form_upload_1"));
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append( "file", $("#edit_first [type=file]")[0].files[0]);
        fd.append( "hid", $("#form_upload_1 [type=hidden]").val());
        alert(fd);
        $("#image_1").html("");
        $.ajax( {
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'save_picture.php',
          data: fd,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
            $("#image_1").html(data);
          }
        });
});
```

}

```
<form id='form_upload_1' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form_upload_1' method='post' action=''>    
   <div id='edit_first' class='upload_button_wrapper'>
    <input id='edit_first' class='upload_button' type='file' onchange='pleaseUpload()' name='file'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='hid' value="first" />
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it because you are posting it to save_picture.php ?

Comment: You're appending the results of a jQuery selector to the FormData, is that correct?

Comment: I have changed the appending part with this, still gives me the same error. var fd=new FormData($("form#form_upload_1"));

Comment: I think this SO thread will be elpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: I have changed my form data to serialize but still gives the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a form to a form data object you have to do it in the constructor

```
var fd = new FormData($("#form_upload_1")[0]);
```

notice I pass the HTMLFormElemnt and not the jQuery object that encapsulates it.

The append method takes strings/Blobs/Files i.e. form field data

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append( "file", $("#edit_first")[0].files[0]);
fd.append( "hid", $("#form_upload_1 [type=hidden]").val());
```

Also you should know that the `id` attribute for html elements should be unique per document.

Comment: I have edited my javascript. Still it wasn't posted to the php file. Do you think the "onchange" attribute of the file affected the script from posting?

Comment: @user3422210 this might be because you have two elements with the same id. Try using the one with the form constructor, or fix your markup.