# Form Event Order - Using Form Data on Frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My problem is simple, yet annoying.  Instead of sending form data to the server, I just want to access the entered data on the front end.  I figured I could do that by using the parameters that show up after I submit the form.

My jQuery submit event, however, is executing before the parameters change on the URL!  My logic, then, doesn't use the correct data.  How do I fix this?  See below:

```
listen: function() {
  $('form').submit(this.init.bind(this))
}
```

I need the URL parameters  to change first, then have this event execute!  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a delay on it. Probably more effective, you could simply use .serialize().

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Serialize works beautifully.  The key is to not get the data from the URL if you need it before the submit event finishes!  THANK YOU!