# how can i get values from serialized form?

Tags: php, jquery

i have this block of code. What I want is to get the values from form control formVal. How can I get those values like key-value pair?

```
alert(jQuery(".dateMasking").serialize());
var formVal = jQuery(".dateMasking").serialize();
alert(formVal['waitlist_opens']);
```

The first alert shows as: `waitlist_opens=2015-03-10`, but the second alert doesn't show as expected: `2015-03-10`

Comment: use .serializeArray();

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get form data with Javascript/Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Got it! Thanks! :)

```
alert(jQuery(".dateMasking").serializeArray());
var formVal = jQuery(".dateMasking").serializeArray();
jQuery.each( formVal, function( i, field ){
    alert(field.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

alter your code with the following to get the date

```
alert(jQuery(".dateMasking").serialize());
var formVal = jQuery(".dateMasking").serialize();
formVal = formVal.split("=");
for(i=0; i<formVal.length; i++) {
alert(formVal[i]);
}
```

Comment: both do the same thing in above example :)

Comment: instaed of this alert (formVal[1]); i could put also this jQuery.each( formVal, function( i, field ) {
                alert(field.value);
            });