# Access information in form input on click of a href

Tags: coldfusion, href, cfform

Is it possible to access information in a form when a link is clicked outside of the form using ColdFusion?

For example: I have a list of products and if you click "Edit" that products info is loaded into a form that the user can update. The link the user had clicked to edit has now toggled to "Save and Continue". MY QUESTION: On Click of "Save and Continue" can I access specific fields in the form to pass to my query? The "Save and Continue" is not an input in the form.

Let me know if that needs more explanation.

Comment: The more usual way to do this is with a save and continue button inside of the form =/ - then you are submitting data.

*If you use Jquery or Javascript you are going to be able to access the inputs*

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery