# Converting field values to array and pass it to php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a form for setting up store timings as follows:

```
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td tabindex="0">Monday</td>
         <td><label class="Storeopen">Open</label></td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_1_open" name="day_1[]" value="16:00"></td>
         <td><label class="Storeclose">Close</label> </td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_1_close" name="close" value="00:00"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td tabindex="0">Tuesday</td>
         <td><label class="Storeopen">Open</label></td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_2_open" name="open" value="16:00"></td>
         <td><label class="Storeclose">Close</label> </td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_2_close" name="close" value="00:00"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td tabindex="0">Wednesday</td>
         <td><label class="Storeopen">Open</label></td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_3_open" name="open" value="16:00"> </td>
         <td><label class="Storeclose">Close</label> </td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_3_close" name="close" value="00:00"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td tabindex="0">Thursday</td>
         <td><label class="Storeopen">Open</label></td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_4_open" name="open" value="16:00"> </td>
         <td><label class="Storeclose">Close</label> </td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_4_close" name="close" value="00:00"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td tabindex="0">Friday</td>
         <td><label class="Storeopen">Open</label></td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_5_open" name="open" value="16:00"> </td>
         <td><label class="Storeclose">Close</label> </td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_5_close" name="close" value="00:00"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td tabindex="0">Saturday</td>
         <td><label class="Storeopen">Open</label></td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_6_open" name="open" value="16:00"> </td>
         <td><label class="Storeclose">Close</label> </td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_6_close" name="close" value="00:00"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td tabindex="0">Sunday</td>
         <td><label class="Storeopen">Open</label></td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_7_open" name="open" value="16:00"> </td>
         <td><label class="Storeclose">Close</label> </td>
         <td><input type="time" id="day_7_close" name="close" value="00:00"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Now. To get data, I am using the following jQuery code:

```
        var newTiming = new Array();
        for(var n=1; n<=7; n++){
            newTiming["day_"+[n]] = {"open": $("#day_"+n+"_open").val(), "close":$("#day_"+n+"_close").val()};
            console.log(newTiming);
        }
```

My problem is I can get the data in the console but when I try to store the array into a hidden text field to pass it to my PHP, I am not getting anywhere.

I tried to put the array in the hidden field by the following code:

```
$("#deliveryTimings").val(JSON.stringify(newTiming));
```

What I need to get is an array in the following form:

```
"day_1" => array(
                 "open" => "16:00",
                 "close" => "00:00"
),
```

This is part of a larger form. I am trying to save each section by jQuery. There is no  tag and lots of other input fields on the page. My save button for each section addresses that particular section. Thats why I cant use serializeArray()? and am using this jQuery code to get the data.

I am hoping to get help from community here. Thank you.

**Update:**
I found the ultimate solution by using jQuery Serialize Object by Paul Maček on https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/how-can-i-get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is part of a larger form. I am trying to save each section by jQuery. There is no tag and lots of other input fields on the page. My save button for each section addresses that particular section. Thats why I cant use serializeArray()? and am using this jQuery code to get the data.

Comment: why don't you  use the name like `day_2[open]` & `day_2[close]` for your day time inputs? This will give you very structured and same data at your server side like you are constructing here in the for loop by simply using `serializeArray()`

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `serializeArray()` to get the form data. And to remove your `for` loop you can give your day open and close fields the `name=""` like this:

```
          <tr>
             <td tabindex="0">Monday</td>
             <td><label class="Storeopen">Open</label></td>
             <td><input type="time" id="day_1_open" name="day_1[open]" value="16:00"></td>
             <td><label class="Storeclose">Close</label> </td>
             <td><input type="time" id="day_1_close" name="day_1[close]" value="00:00"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td tabindex="0">Tuesday</td>
             <td><label class="Storeopen">Open</label></td>
             <td><input type="time" id="day_2_open" name="day_2[open]" value="16:00"></td>
             <td><label class="Storeclose">Close</label> </td>
             <td><input type="time" id="day_2_close" name="day_2[close]" value="00:00"></td>
          </tr>
```

By renaming your fields like you should get the data organized by day number at your server side.

Comment: Thanks Sagar. I found the best solution on here: https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Comment: Great, but if you would have used above solution, then also you would get the same result at your server side `$_POST` or `$_GET` array, without using any plugin.

Comment: I've tested the solution you provided. The array given is not in the correct format. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In which format do you need data and how you are getting it with this solution?