# Capturing User data from dynamically generated forms (Jquery-Form-Builder.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, formbuilder

I am using **JQuery FormBuilder plugin** to generate different form for organizational needs and let the *employees* to fill the forms as per requirement. For this purpose we use the **JQuery Form Builder plugin**

> form-builder.js

and

> form-render.js

We have created form building and form rendering modules.Now we could not figure out how to **save the user input data back to DB**. Is there any in-built way to get this done? 
 I would prefer to **store the user inputs in XML/JSON format**, so that I could use that to render the filled form when user tries to edit or provide Save and Submit Later Functionality. Is it possible to achieve with this plug in ? Is there any hack to do that? It will be really helpful.

https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder

Answer (score 2):

it does not appear to be built into this plugin, but its built into jquery see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/how-can-i-get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery)

```
$('#form').serialize()
$('#form').serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can now use the .userData method

from their documentation: https://formbuilder.online/docs/formRender/actions/userData/

```
var formRenderOptions = {
  formData: '[{"type":"text","label":"Text Field","name":"text-1526099104236","subtype":"text"}]';
}
var formRenderInstance = $('#render-container').formRender(formRenderOptions);
console.log(formRenderInstance.userData);
// "[{"type":"text","label":"Full Name","name":"text-1526099104236","subtype":"text","userData":["John Smith"]}]"
```