# FormData constructor isn't getting any values from the form

Tags: javascript

I must be making a very stupid mistake, but I can't figure out why this isn't working:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test a form</h1>
        <form id="myform" name="myform" action="/server">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="johndoe">
            <input type="number" name="id" value="123456">
            <input type="submit" onclick="return sendForm(this.form);">
        </form>

        <script>

            function sendForm(form) {
                var formData = new FormData(form);
                console.log("as json: " + JSON.stringify(formData));
                return false; // Prevent page from submitting.
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

According to the documentation of FormData, if you give it a form object in the constructor, it will populate itself with the form values, but when I do this, I get an empty result in the console. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in this? I tried in both Chrome and Firefox and got the same results. This is based on the example from html5rocks XHR2.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong here. You need to use the methods like `.entires()`, `.get()`, `.getAll()` and so on to access the values, or keys. I had the same issue some time ago, and if you need to convert your `FormData` to JSON, you need to write some code, which does this for you, `JSON.stringify()`
 does not work in this case.
Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Or, if you need a jQuery solution: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/how-can-i-get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I need to do. It's simple:

```
console.log("Here it is: " + JSON.stringify($('#myform').serializeArray()[0]));
```

Gives the expected result: a JSON string containing name / value pairs from the form. I can then send this using XMLHttpRequest. No reason to use a FormData object in this case.