# Using Ajax in meta-box button on post.php

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have created a plugin that creates a custom Post Type called `smm_newsletter`, and used that Post Type to create newsletter template and send a newsletter email. Then, I made a meta-box for sending button include in that Post Type's post-new.php/post.php.

The script for wp_localize_script is this

```
function smm_admin_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'smm-js-priv-script', plugins_url( '/js/private/smm-builder.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    // localize admin URL
    $php_localized_priv_script = array( 'admin_url' => admin_url() );
    wp_localize_script( 'smm-js-priv-script', 'smm_priv_script', $php_localized_priv_script );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'smm-js-priv-script' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'smm_admin_scripts' );
```

*I added exactly same localized admin URL to my public scripts function and it work fine in `input` submit button. This code too, it work fine in `input` submit button.

This is code for that button

```
// I do not use type="submit" because publish/update button use it.
<input id="smm_newsletter_send" name="smm_newsletter_send" type="button" value="Send Newsletter">
```

and ajax

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    /* Newsletter Section */
    // I did localized script for path to wp-admin here
    var wpajax_url = smm_priv_script.admin_url + 'admin-ajax.php';
    var sendingNewsletter_url = wpajax_url + '?action=smm_newsletter_sender';
    // out put form console: http://localhost/wordpressProject/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=smm_newsletter_sender
    console.log(sendingNewsletter_url);
    $( '#smm_newsletter_send' ).on( 'click', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $form = $( 'form#post' );
        // setup our form data for ajax post
        var form_data = $form.serialize();
        console.log( form_data ); // here it work find
        // submit form data with ajax post
        $.ajax({
            'method' : 'post',
            'url' : sendingNewsletter_url,
            'data' : form_data,
            'dataType' : 'json',
            'catch' : false,
            'success' : function( data, textStatus ){
                if( data.status == 1 ) {
                    // success
                    // notify the user of success
                    window.location.reload( true );
                    console.log( data.status + '\n' );
                    console.log( data.message + '\n' + '——————————' );
                } else {
                    // error
                    // begin building our error message text
                    console.log( data.status + ' ' + 'error' + '\n' );
                    console.log( data.message + '\n' + '——————————' );
                }
            },
            'error' : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                // ajax didn't work
                console.log('A jQuery Ajax error has occurred! See details below...');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
        // stop the form from submitting nornally
        return false;
    });
});
```

But, after I clicked that button `ajax()` only console.log undefined for me

```
undefined error
undefined
——————————
```

So, I tried another method to test my sending newsletter function [`smm_newsletter_sender()`] to make sure that function works, by changing `$_POST`  to `$_GET`. And simply placed URL that look like this `http://localhost/wordpressProject/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=smm_newsletter_sender?post_ID=123`. It worked perfectly, by sending all of newsletter emails and returning the proper JSON. My email sending function is working fine, but the button for send not, why?.

At first, I had suspected about `ajax()`, may I did something wrong about it? But I did not found anything wrong. So, may be It about WordPress itself that prevent something that I don't know.

Comment: replace $ with `jQuery`

Comment: Sorry to make you confuse. For jQuery code above, I wraped in

jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

    // Code above is in here

});

Comment: Please show your `wp_localize_script`

Comment: @brasofilo for that, you can see my `wp_localize_script` after I edit my question. thank

Comment: Your question should include all code necessary to evaluate the problem.

Comment: Sorry for that  @brasofilo. I have already added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to print our scripts only on the pages we need. This is important because we don't want our styles/scripts printing all over `wp-admin`.

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'smm_admin_script');
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'smm_admin_script');
```

Also:

- check if it's the correct Post Type before printing the scripts:
- localize the full admin-ajax URL
- localize the security nonce

```
function smm_admin_script() {
    global $typenow;
    if( 'smm_newsletter' !== $typenow )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script('my-ajax', plugins_url( '/my-ajax.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 
        'my-ajax', 
        'my_plugin',
        array( 
            'ajaxnonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'nonce_smm' ),
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        ) 
    );
}
```

The file `my-ajax.js` will use the localized values `my_plugin.ajaxnonce` and `my_plugin.ajaxurl`. The `action` is defined on the Ajax PHP function.

For testing I used `button#send-ajax` and `div#aresponse`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $( '#send-ajax' ).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            action: 'sendform_smm',
            security: my_plugin.ajaxnonce,
            form_smm: { 'input1': 'value1', 'input2': 'value2' }
        };
        /* 
           You can send the full form as an object using:
           form_smm: $form.serializeArray()
        */ 
        $.post( 
            my_plugin.ajaxurl, 
            data,                   
            function( response ){
                // ERROR HANDLING
                if( !response.success ) {
                    // No data came back, maybe a server error
                    if( !response.data )
                        $( '#aresponse' ).html( 'AJAX ERROR: no response' );
                    else
                        $( '#aresponse' ).html( response.data.error );
                }
                else
                    $( '#aresponse' ).html( response.data );
            }
        ); 
    });
});
```

The Ajax function checks the nonce, you make your thing and return Error or Success:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sendform_smm', 'sendform_smm_callback' );
function sendform_smm_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'nonce_smm', 'security' );

    # Form values sent by JS
    $received_data = $_POST['form_smm']; 
    # Read the data sent and send it back just for testing purposes.
    $text = 'Input Field: ' . $received_data['input1'];
    # Your form actions
    $do_your_thing = true;
    if( !$do_your_thing )
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'error' => __( 'Error message.' ) ) );
    else
        wp_send_json_success( $text );
}
```

Comment: This may be useful: [How can I get form data with JavaScript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24012884/1287812)

Comment: I have two questions @brasofilo. First. Can I get form directly from `$( 'form#post' );` in post/post-new.php? Or, should I not do that, the thing I must do is to localize everything I want for sending the form from `wp_localize_script`? Second. Why when I use `a` tag for button and method `GET` everything work fine? Or, is this not the problem at all?

Comment: And @brasofilo , thank for yours enqueue script pattern, that is really cool!

Comment: Localize is only for the information that JavaScript cannot get by itself. Everything else that's on HTML you can access with jQuery, like the `form#post`. . . . . No difference between `<button>` or `<a>`, the thing is that you must prevent it from submitting the `form#post` (I understand that's the custom post type title, content, etc...)

Comment: Thank for your answer, @brasofilo . I will try it again around next week to figure it out what wrong I did, after I recover form cold. :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ajax url displaying undefined.
You need to localize your script first like:

wp_register_script('myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.1', TRUE);

```
$protocol = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

wp_localize_script('myscript', 'ajax_obj', array('admin_ajax' =>admin_url('admin-ajax.php',$protocol)));
// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
```

Then in your .js file read admin URL like :`ajax_obj.admin_ajax`.

Comment: On code above, I had already did it. `smm_priv_script.admin_url` received localized script form the PHP file. but thank.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried in many ways to solve this problem. OK, I don't know why, but this make it work. At first, I changed method form POST to GET and `input` button to `a`.

This is happen in custom meta-box.

```
// I created nonce url for security thing
$nonce_url = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=smm_newsletter_sender&post_ID=' . $post->ID ), basename( __FILE__ ), 'smm_send_newsletter_nonce' );
// and changed inupt to a tag
echo( '<div><a href="' . $nonce_url . '" id="smm_newsletter_send" class="button button-primary button-large">Send Newsletter</a>' );
```

and in jQuery `ajax()`

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    $( '#smm_newsletter_send' ).on( 'click', function( e ){
        $.ajax({
            'method' : 'GET',
            'url' : $( this ).attr( 'href' ),
            'dataType' : 'json',
            'catch' : false,
            'success' : function( data, textStatus ){
                if( data.status == 1 ) {
                    // success
                    // notify the user of success
                    window.location.reload( true );
                    console.log( data.status + '\n' );
                    console.log( data.message + '\n' + '——————————' );
                } else {
                    // error
                    // begin building our error message text
                    console.log( data.status + 'error' + '\n' );
                    console.log( data.message + '\n' + '——————————' );
                }
            },
            'error' : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                // ajax didn't work
                console.log('A jQuery Ajax error has occurred! See details below...');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }

        });
        e.preventDefault();

        // stop the form from submitting nornally
        return false;
    });
});
```

As I said above, I don't know why this work and, in case of input button, why `ajax()` can not sent the request URL to sending action. So, this is only a practical way.

If someone can explain, please do it.

Thank.