# jQuery Ajax to php get form data in structured array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a form which contains multiple group fields.Which is posted via ajax on.
Everything is okay.I just need to create an array to send it to the backend.I am using serializeArray().may be it is wrong form to send data.That's why i am geting error

```
<form method="post" id="tasks-multiform">
<div id="people-container">
    <h3>Person 1:</h3>
    <p>
        <label>First name</label><br>
        <input name="people[1][first_name]">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Last name</label><br>
        <input name="people[1][last_name]">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input name="people[1][email]">
    </p>

    <h3>Person 2:</h3>
    <p>
        <label>First name</label><br>
        <input name="people[2][first_name]">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Last name</label><br>
        <input name="people[2][last_name]">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input name="people[2][email]">
    </p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" id="add-new-person" class="add-new-person">Add! new person</a>

<p>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</p>
</form>
```

Above is the form and data is posted via ajax.And below is jquery codes..avoid `action` its wp backend function

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', '#tasks-multiform', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var form = jQuery('form#tasks-multiform');
var data = form.serializeArray();
console.log(data);
jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : admin_ajax.ajax_url,
    data : {
        action : 'utasks',
        tasksdata : data,
        tasksnums : tasksnums,
    },
    beforeSend : function(){
        jQuery('.tasksubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    },
});
});
```

i wanted somethin like :

```
{"1"=>
    {
       "first_name"=>"", 
       "last_name"=>"", 
       "email"=>""
    }, 
 "2"=>
    {
       "first_name"=>"", 
       "last_name"=>"", 
       "email"=>""
    }
 }
```

But what i am getting:

```
{"1"=>
    {
       "[prople][1][first_name]"=>"", 
    }, 
 "2"=>
    {
       "[prople][1][last_name]"=>"", 
    }, 
 "3"=>
    {
       "[prople][1][email]"=>"", 
    }, 
 "4"=>
    {
       "[prople][2][first_name]"=>"",
    } 
 "5"=>
    {
       "[prople][2][last_name]"=>"", 
    } 
 "6"=>
    {
       "[prople][1][email]"=>""
    }
 }
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need to serialize array as you already have it in an array called 'people'.

Comment: @GavinThomas So how can i get data to send to ajax?

Comment: You can just use `.serialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using `reduce()` function ([see this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012884/5313715)). Then, you just have to use a loop to get your data.

Example :

```
var data = form.serializeArray().reduce(function(obj, item) {
    obj[item.name] = item.value;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

With this, you get this data :

```
{
    "people[1": {
        "first_name": "Lorem",
        "last_name": "L",
        "email": "lorem@example.com"
    },
    "people[2": {
        "first_name": "Ipsum",
        "last_name": "I",
        "email": "ipsum@example.com"
    }
}
```

Now you can just loop inside your object, or find a workaround to get either nice indexes instead of `people[1`, `people[2`, .. or an array of object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) as such :

```
formData = new FormData(jQuery('form#tasks-multiform')[0]);
formData.append("action", "utasks");
formData.append("tasksnums", tasksnums);
```

Then send it with `data : formData` in your `.ajax()` parameters.

Yet another option is to take a look at this [serialize object plugin](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object).

Hope this help !