# How to save input field in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created two component `App` and `Inner` component  App component contain a form .

My Inner component is containing a const Data further i passed that to  dangerouslySetInnerHTML to set inner html .  So there can be any number of input field . Sometime it can have 3 to 5 input field .

Is it possible in React? As i see i can't have two way binding at this scenario.

As i believe its not possible in React?

[Demo Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-ptolemy-e01wh?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const handleSubmission = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Inner />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmission}>
        <div>Both two values comma separated: </div>
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const data = {
  htmltag: `<html><style>table {  font-family: arial, sans-serif;  border-collapse: collapse;  width: 40%;}td, th {  border: 1px solid #dddddd;  text-align: left;  padding: 8px;}tr:nth-child(even) {  background-color: #dddddd;}</style><body> <table> <tbody> <tr> <th>1</th> <th>2</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Hello</td> <td><input type = "text" /></td> </tr>  <tr> <td>Welcome</td> <td><input type = "text" /></td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </body></html>`
};

export default function Inner() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.htmltag }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you mean saving the input value?

Comment: How tied are you to using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? Would it be possible in your project to change the data to be in JSON format instead? If you're open to switching, I have some ideas on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get access to this data in a React-type way, however you can get access to this data using plain JavaScript, which React supports. Basically you can't treat these inputs as [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), instead as [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

This means however that you won't get state updates in real time like you do with controlled components, but you can still get access to the data. You'll just have to get the data from the DOM when you need it (e.g. upon submission).

Since you also won't be able to pass refs directly to these components, you'll have to query the DOM. You can start with a ref for your container (the one whose inner HTML gets dangerously set) and then query for `input` elements (and/or the other input-like elements).

Here's an example:

**App.js**

```js
export default function App() {
  const dataContainerRef = React.useRef(null);

  const handleSubmission = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputs = Array.from(dataContainerRef.current.querySelectorAll("input"));
    // if your inputs have unique names:
    const formData = Object.fromEntries(inputs.map(input => [input.name, input.value]));
    // or just get an array of the values:
    const formDataArray = inputs.map(input => input.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Inner dataContainerRef={ dataContainerRef } />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmission}>
        <div>Both two values comma separated: </div>
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Inner.js**

```js
export default function Inner(props) {
  const { dataContainerRef } = props;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div
        ref={dataContainerRef}
        className="data-container"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.htmltag }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-sky-bn452).

Note that you can look into [this question about getting form data with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/how-can-i-get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery) if you want to know about other ways you can get the form data using plain JS (I'd recommend *not* importing jQuery into your React project).

**Alternate Approach**

If you're open to changing the structure of your data so that that `data` is not an HTML string and instead is in JSON format, you can dynamically create the `input` elements yourself and control them like normal.

For example, if you structure `data` like this:

```js
const data = {
    inputNames: ["Hello", "Welcome"],
}
```

Then you can create `formData` of the form:

```js
{
    Hello: "",
    Welcome: "",
}
```

which should be stored in the parent of `Inner` because it owns the submission function.

Then you'll just need to initialize the `formData` from `data` and then dynamically create an `input` element for each `inputName` given.

Here's a sample of `Inner`:

```js
export default function Inner(props) {
  const { formData, setFormData } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // initialize `formData`
    setFormData(
      Object.fromEntries(data.inputNames.map(inputName => [inputName, ""]))
    );
  }, [setFormData]);

  const inputRows = data.inputNames.map(inputName => (
    <tr key={inputName}>
      <td>{inputName}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          name={inputName}
          value={formData[inputName]}
          onChange={event => {
            event.persist();
            setFormData(prev => ({
              ...prev,
              [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            }));
          }}
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <table>
        <tbody>{inputRows}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-raman-c1wcz).

Comment: Can you give a codesandbox demo?  because its not running @Henry Woody

Comment: @Khushboo I think so, you just need to pass the form data on to whatever function you need within `handleSubmit`. Also I updated my answer with an alternate approach.