# How to get form data from the payload using jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

As I am trying to fetch the form data from the URL as its a return URL which I am receiving. Is there any way where I can fetch the form data in jQuery. I am also aware of $_POST in PHP but I am searching for a solution on JQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You could use fetch:

`fetch(<URL>, {method: 'POST', body: <data>})`

If you need to use jQuery, jQuery has a method called post:

`$.post(<URL>,<data>)`

Comment: The URL is sending me form data and I need to fetch that data. But in your answer the methods are sending data to server. But I am receiving data from server already.

Comment: Then I think you want to check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/how-can-i-get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery) instead