# Multiple Forms on Page Submit Data for Specific One

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a page that has multiple forms on it, when you submit one of the forms (via Ajax) it works, however when I submit any other form but that first one, it posts the data of the 1st form and not the 2nd form. I think it has something to do with the .each() function or to find that click to that form, but not sure how and I am stuck. Here is my code so far, any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

```
$(".mixForm").submit(function (event) {

event.preventDefault();
          
var headline =  $(".expHeadline").val();
var content = $(".expContent").val();
var vid = $(".IDv").val();
alert(headline);
 
// This does the ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        'action': 'enyc_add_exp_row',
        'head' : headline,
        'cont' : content,
        'vid' : vid,
        
    },
    success:function(data) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        alert('hi');
        console.log(data);
         $(".response").html(data);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: you are grabbing the value from input class name, grab the actual form data using `form.serialize` or `formData`, so each form submit has its own data [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/how-can-i-get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: you can just do `data: $(this).serialize() + '&action=enyc_add_exp_row'`, just make sure your input name corresponds to what you need need to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `.expHeadline`, `.expContent` and `.IDv` are elements inside each forms ?

If so, there is no specific context for them so jQuery is using the first element he found on your dom, not on the submitted form.

Better target this elements with `this` on your function. `this` refered to the element targeted by the `submit` event

```
var headline =  $(this).find(".expHeadline").val();
var content = $(this).find(".expContent").val();
var vid = $(this).find(".IDv").val();
```