# PHP bulk form post using ajax

Tags: php

I have a form with 100 fields ,how do i post the data to a php using ajax with out refreshing  the page,also 
i do not want to concatenate the  field values without 
getelementbyid in the xmlhttprequest.

Thanks

Comment: Pick a JavaScript library, use its form serialization and AJAX methods.

Comment: Or iterate through the dom and get all the values of the form fields and make a string... you can have it as a function... please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jQuery could be something like

```
$.post("/path", $("#form-id").serialize(), function(ev){
  alert("done!");
});
```