# Text box value issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I insert a text box into my page with jQuery `.html("<input type="text>")`

Once I click a button, I loop through `($("input[type=text]).each)` and then need to get the value of each text box. 
When I try to get that `val()` of that text box it returns empty string, although I have typed something in there

```
console.log($(v).val()) = "empty string"
```

EDIT

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function(k, v) {
                console.log($(v).val());
            });
```

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: you could give us some code to see :)

Comment: Could you add you `.each()` loop ?

Comment: Your loop seems fine. If none of the answers solve your problem, please post the code you use to insert the input.

Comment: `v` is the value if the element. You don't want to wrap it in a jQuery object (see my answer below)

Comment: see similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

If you are appending to the DOM you should look into using jQuerys live method:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I am using live with all my events

Comment: @Harry you're adding elements after the document is loaded, your .each won't work, .live will. See the .live docs I linked to

Comment: @marto have you read the question? He iterates over inputs *on button click*. It's not that the click handler never executes, it's that values are empty.

Comment: @katspaugh that part must have been added when they edited their post.

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
 $('#myForm').live('click', function() {
    // get all the inputs into an array.
    var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');

    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });

});
```

either use  [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
 $('form').submit(function() {
  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I suspect for the same reason I got downvoted and called out by  katspaugh. The quesiton has been edited several times since it's inital post, wasting everyones time

Comment: The inputs selector is wrong, by the way. Should be `$('#myForm input');`.

Comment: @katspaugh; have u seen the line under that function???

Comment: Actually, there *is* `:input` selector (http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/). Mea culpa.

Comment: @katspaugh would you like to tell me what is the difference between those??

Comment: `input` is a standard tag-name selector (see http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/); `:input` is jQuery's own selector that matches all form elements: actual input elements, buttons and textareas.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for this, I actually see now that me problem was from something ells in my app and not what I was thinking it is. Sorry for wasting time