# Send Variable Number of Fields in jQuery's Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, search

How might one pass a variable number of fields to [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)'s second parameter? I am attempting to enhance my search with ajax, and have been following Symfony's [Jobeet tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/18). Unfortunately, in addition to the text field, I have a list of hidden fields I would like passed. I can't [serialise](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) all of the form's inputs, because I have to perform an operation on the text field first.

The function looks something like this:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(key)
{
  // do something to the value
  var query = this.value;

  $('#results').load(
    $(this).parents('form').attr('action'),
    // pass query along with all hidden fields
    { query: query, /* variable number of hidden input fields go here */ }
  );
}
```

One option might have been to serialise all fields but the 'search' input, append the modified `query` variable and pass that string. However, short of [getting all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery) and looping through them, creating the string manually, I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the object in a loop:

```
var params = { query: query };
$('#form input[type="hidden"]').each(function() {
    params[this.name] = $(this).val();
});

$('#results').load(
    $(this).parents('form').attr('action'), params
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Not sure why I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the [serializeObject()](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject) plugin.