# jquery getting data from form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I'm trying to get data from a form using jquery and validate it. What is the best way to take data from a form to a variable using jquery?

Comment: use jquery selector to get value

Comment: Another question similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the snippet that you can use -

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    // get all the inputs into an array.
    var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');

    // not sure if you wanted this, but I thought I'd add it.
    // get an associative array of just the values.
    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });

});
```

Got it from [stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Well here we go

*This is the **jQuery** script:*

```
function getData () {

$(document).ready(function() {
   var myTextFieldValue = $('#myTextField').value;
   alert('The value is: '+myTextFieldValue);
 });

}
```

*This is the **HTML***

```
<form action='#' method='whatever'>
 <input type='text' id='myTextField' />
 <input type='submit' onClick='getData()' />
</form>
```

***NOTE:***
In order to make your script working **you must import the jQuery Libraries**

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I Did not try the script so there could be some errors.
Hope i was helpful to you
Bye.

(For any help pm me)

Comment: how can somebody PM you. we can just leave comments.

Answer (score 0):

there no way to get all the data from a form in one line of code. You have to retrieve it value by value.
if you have a `<input id='some-id' >`
just use `var someId = $('#some-id').val();`. Now someId hold the value of the input

The val() function only return the value of the first matched element (if you don't know what i mean take a look at jquery selector (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
take a look at http://api.jquery.com/val/ to see the val function, it has some weird thing with the `<textarea>` tag

And remember to always validate server side, even if you already did it client side, js securrity is very easy to bypass

Comment: there is a way to get all the data from a form in one line of code using '$('#myform').serialize();'

Comment: @BishnuPaudel how do you then take serialized data and use it?

Comment: @gilbertbw serializeArray() might be useful in your use case. http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery Validation plugin. Have a look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Using_remote_validation_to_help_with_captchas)