# How to get all input fields from a form in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obtain form input fields using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery)

I have a *form* with many *input fields*.

What is the easiest way to get all the input fields of that form in an `array`?

Or the Object in `Key:Value` pair

Comment: Do you want to get references to the DOM elements or values of the fields? Are the input fields all of the same type (tag) or different ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object of all the inputs:-

```
$("form#formId :input").each(function(){
    var input = $(this); // A jquery object of the input
});
```

or

```
$('#formId').submit(function() {
    // get the array of all the inputs 
    var $inputs = $('#formId :input');

    // get an associative array of the values
    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

This one returns the `Key:Value` pair -

```
var values = {};
$.each($('#formId').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    values[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `serializeArray()` jQuery function:

```
var fields = $('#formID').serializeArray();
```

To get an associative array of the data (a JSON Object with name/value mappings), have a look at the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/349012

Comment: Thanks. But the solution is not giving me the array specifically the associative ones. But surely helped me to reach the point, i was looking for

Comment: So you wanted to create an associative array of keys -> values? (essentially a JSON Object of them?) If so, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/349012 . It uses the serializeArray function as well, just reformats the data!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy:

```
$('input','#formId')
```

or

```
$('#formId').find('input');
```

Comment: find api is quite expensive, and it is hanging up my browser... I have couple of tons inputs

Answer (score -2):

Use: `var allInputs = $(":input");`

Comment: This will return all the input type no matter, which form they belongs to

Comment: I've seen this get new developers confused. Needs a better selector.