# serializing form values where name is blah[email]

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an html form where the name values are:

```
name="main[name]"
name="main[email]"
name="main[info]"
```

How would I go about getting all the values of the array in the form of:

```
main : { name : 'value', email : 'value', info : 'value' }
```

I've tried jquery's `serialize()` from an older stack ([Obtain form input fields using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery)) question but that solution gives me an array along the lines of

```
{ 'main[email]' : 'value', 'main[email]' : 'value', 'main[info]' : 'value' }
```

EDIT: reason i'm doing the `main[email]` format is because I have an extra input there for csrf which I need to differentiate from the actual input values, the final array is gonna be something like:

```
  [ csrf: '', main : { name : 'value', email : 'value', info : 'value' } ]
```

this way I can just use `main` values.

Comment: Hehe, and people called me crazy for rejecting jQuery and writing my own code... Who's laughing now, when I have beautifully serialized forms that include the button you clicked and even the coordinates of an image input! :3

Comment: If you are looking to pass along arrays as values, you will have to manually create the array and drop them into the value on the post

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8407771/597419

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol While I am not fanboy of jQuery, that functionality could just as easily be created using jQuery. No one calls anyone crazy for not using a framework -- when it is appropriate to not use a framework.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just set your fields like this?

```
 name="name"
 name="email"
 name="info"
```

Comment: looking for a way to loop all the data into an array

Comment: @cat-t If you named your fields as suggested, `serialize()` would give you an "array" with the data and appropriate keys (actually, an object that you can treat like an associative array)