# jQuery accessing children: get form input in an associative array when inputs are in an HTML table

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm making multiple forms from a script and want to be able to post an associative array of the fieldnames and values using Ajax without needing to know the fieldnames. This seemed like the perfect solution:

[Obtain form input fields using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery)

However, no matter what I do, when I run `var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');`, `console.log($inputs)` logs an empty array. I've basically copy-pasted multiple methods from stackoverflow that worked for others, and I consistently have that bug. So I'm wondering if `'#myForm :input'` doesn't see the input fields in my case because my form is in a table. If so, how can I build an associative array if my form is formatted this way?

```
<tr>
<form id='myForm'>
<td><input type='text' name='foo'></td>
...
</form>
</tr>
```

Comment: A form in a `tr` is invalid HTML.

Comment: ok, I'll put it in a div. Thank you