# How to get Html from DOM along with input data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a web application where i have to send HTML from the DOM along with values of respective text areas and textboxes. Currently , I am using innerHTML for accomplishing this.

Lets suppose we have an html script

```
<div id="abcd">
   <form id="form1" >
      <input type="text" id="input1" />
   </form>
</div>
```

Now, on the html page in browser, I fill the text box with some value (say - "12345").
And, I try to capture complete html using

```
var x = $("#abcd").html();  // or 
var x = document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML ;
```

All I get in x is

```
<div id="abcd">
   <form id="form1" >
      <input type="text" id="input1" />
   </form>
</div>
```

Although I wanted something like -

```
<div id="abcd">
   <form id="form1" >
      <input type="text" id="input1" value="abcd" />
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to submit a form?

Comment: @JK. - sorry for incomplete question... I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong selector to get the area of text input. Try to use "#input1". Like this to get your text area value

```
var x = $("#input1").val();
```

This will capture the text entered by user.
Then use variable x to create compleete HTML

```
var y = '<div id="abcd"><form id="form1" ><input type="text" id="input1" value=' + x + "/>   </form></div>"
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qMcJ9/
PS. I do not know what event you are using so I connected it t .keyup event, You can change it any way you want

Comment: I have around 20 input fields, so doing this manually is cumbersome. I mean we can do that, but I was hoping if there is already built functions to do so.

Comment: Then just save your values into an array (id -> value) and then assign them back to each input field. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery