# I want to get input field value with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I am writing a programme i am printing from mysql with php in a table i want to get input field value by the help of jquery how can i get each input value using jquery.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, name, price, qty FROM appetisers";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
         $quantity = $row["qty"]; 
         if ($quantity == '' || $quantity == '0') {
              $quantity = '1';
           }  

        ?>
        <tr class="eachrow">
            <td><?php echo $row["name"] ?></td>
            <td class="price-amount">£ <?php echo $row["price"] ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="amount-type" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>"/></td>
            <td><a href="" class="add-cart">Add to cart</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain form input fields using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.add-cart').click(function(e){
    var val = $(e.target).closest('.eachrow').find('[ name="amount"]').val();
   console.log(val);
})
```

Comment: All inputs will have the same name of 'amount'

Comment: Think i have 13 rows in table in which there is a input.How can i get each input value?

Comment: Then you have to run a loop. I've edited the answer.

Comment: i want to get each value when corresponding add to cart is clicked

Comment: Then you've add the click callback function. See the latest function.

Comment: I dont want to get a array.I just want the clicked item's value.only clicked item's value

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you'd need to give you inputs some sort of identifyer for example add and increment so your inputs can have id's such as 
`'appetisers_' . $increment`

Then you can get these with jquery and get the value using

```
$('#appetisers_3').val();
```

At the moment you have a name on the inouts, but they will all have the same name

Answer (score 0):

By using Jquery `val()` you can get the value of text field like this

```
var Values = $( ".amount-type" ).val();
```

i think it will  work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.amount-type').each(function() {
    console.log( this.val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script> 
   var TableData = new Array();
    $('table tr.eachrow').each(function(row, tr){
        TableData[row]={
                    "amount" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').val()
            }
    }); 
    TableData.shift();
 </script>
```