# Accessing form elements under submit function without defining the form name

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I do have a form and submitting it via a submit function. Bur for submission variable I'm not utilizing document id but classes.

```js
$(".modalform").submit(function(event) {
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();
  // get all the inputs into an array.
  var $inputs = $('this :input');
  console.log($inputs.val())
  /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
  var $form = $(this),
    url = $form.attr('action');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Could be seen that this submit function is not based on ids but classes. I do have multiple forms with different ids and same class names and when I submit each of them, I want to have their elements and values in an array. There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169506/obtain-form-input-fields-using-jquery) answer but it takes form ids an argument. I want an approach that could get the submitted forms id by any means and serialize values according to that (the mentioned answer can be used after obtaining form id).

Comment: `$(this).find(':input')` <= your selector is wrong

Comment: I fixed your snippet. Please add the rendered HTML in the correct frame

Comment: `var $inputs = $(':input',this);`

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for correcting. This now works for inputs, but I need a way to get all form elements and their corresponding values into an array so I can manipulate them.

Comment: I'd love to see a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You get the values like this

```js
$(".modalform").submit(function(event) {
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();
  // get all the inputs into an array.
  var $inputs = $(this).find(':input');
  const vals = $inputs.map(function() { return this.value }).get()
  console.log(vals)
  /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
  var $form = $(this),
    url = $form.attr('action');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```